# Angular transition area below collapsing up against navigation

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I am very new to all things Angular and have been experimenting with some stuff. 
Been playing with UI-Router and with Angular Animations.

So far everything is going to plan, except one thing.

During the transition between pages (my top-most states) the footer area collapses up under the main content and against the navigation. 
(I'm also fairly new to css transitions, so my knowledge is limited, but growing)

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this from happening? Maybe have it snag on to the height of whichever state is the tallest? (IE, the one leaving, or the one entering)

(I've tried searching everywhere, but whatever I search for I come up dry. Maybe I'm searching the wrong keywords.)

I have included a [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/lab8iO9lNNRj7Ofcl2J6/preview) link

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You dont have any content on other pages so the footer moves up? im not sure i follow... are you talking about the brief moment when the text in the footer moves into the white area underneath the nav?

Comment: Yes. If you click the links you'll see the the footer moves right up against the navigation, then only when the transition has finished does it drop back down.
This is most visible if you click Home from any of the other pages.